# Why is $\|A-BCA\|_F^2$ non-convex regarding $B,C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, convex-analysis

I noticed somewhere, a function similar to $\|A-BCA\|_F^2$ was claimed to be non-convex regarding $B$ or $C$ individually, while a relaxation like $D=CA$ makes $\|A-BD\|_F^2$ convex respect to each $B$ and $D$ individually. The matrices $A, B, C, D$ are not square-matrix, and by *individually*, I mean assuming the value of one matrix fixed while analyzing w.r.t the other matrix.

Honestly, I do not understand why the first one is non-convex while the latter is convex?

**Update:**

In fact, i fund the above claim in 
[This NIPS paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5600-projective-dictionary-pair-learning-for-pattern-classification.pdf), where they claimed that Eq. 5 is not a convex problem w.r.t $P_k$, but the relaxation in Eq. 6 makes the objective convex w.r.t to each of the components.

Comment: I doubt that the latter function is convex. Even in the one-dimensional case, $f(x,y) = (1-xy)^2$ is not convex in $(x,y)$.

Comment: @gerw: I meant considering convexity w.r.t one matrix at a time. In your 1-D example, $f(x,y)$ is convex w.r.t $x$ or $y$ individually.

Comment: If you are interested in this separate convexity, also the first function should be convex (w.r.t. this notion).

Comment: @gerw: how can you show that?!

Comment: @gerw: I'm especially interested in the convexity of the first function regarding $C$!

Answer (score 1):

Let us check that the first function is convex w.r.t. $C$. Thus, we have to show that the function
$$t \mapsto \| A - B \, (C + t \, D) \, A\|_F$$
is convex for all matrices $D$. Let us abbreviate $G := A - B \, C \, A$ and $H := B \, D \, A$. Then,
$$
\|A - B \, (C + t \, D) \, A\|_F
=
\|G - t \, H\|_F^2
=
\|G\|_F^2 - 2 \, t \, (G,H)_F + t^2 \, \|H\|_F^2$$
and this function is clearly convex w.r.t. $t$. Here, $(\cdot,\cdot)_F$ is the Frobenius inner product.

Comment: So, you are saying that a function $f(X)$ would be convex w.r.t matrix $X$ if $f(X+tY)$ is convex w.r.t the scalar $t$?

Comment: Also, does it mean that they made a wrong claim in https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5600-projective-dictionary-pair-learning-for-pattern-classification.pdf 
regarding the convexity of Eq. 5 w.r.t each of its component?

Comment: I do not see any statement w.r.t. separate convexity of (5). They only say that (5) is not convex.

Comment: Then what was the point of converting (5) to (6) given (5) is separately convex? Couldn't they apply the same optimization procedure directing on (5)?